# no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect();

Tags: c++, qt

Есть кнопка в `ob_panel.ui` - `on_pB_Switch_clicked` и элемент в `mainwindow.ui` - `MapToolKit`.
Пытаюсь при нажатии на кнопку в `ob_panel.ui` скрыть элемент находящийся в `mainwindow.ui`.

> MainWindow.cpp

```
connect(&Ob_Panel, &ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked, this, &MainWindow::switchVideoMap);

void MainWindow::switchVideoMap(){
    ui->MapToolKit->hide();
}
```

> MainWindow.h

```
#include <ob_panel.h>
private slots:
   void switchVideoMap();
private:
   ob_panel *Ob_Panel
```

> ob_panel.cpp

```
void ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked(){
}
```

> ob_panel.h

```
public:
  void on_pB_Switch_clicked();
```

При компиляции вылетает ошибка

```
../mainwindow.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(ob_panel**, void (ob_panel::*)(), MainWindow* const, void (MainWindow::*)())'
     connect(&Ob_Panel, &ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked, this, &MainWindow::switchVideoMap);
                                                                                          ^
```

Comment: public:
  void on_pB_Switch_clicked(); <- это сигнал или слот? Укажи это правильно: signals:
  void on_pB_Switch_clicked();


или public slots:
  void on_pB_Switch_clicked();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ob_Panel` у вас и так указатель, брать у него адрес в `connect` не нужно

```
connect(Ob_Panel, &ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked, this, &MainWindow::switchVideoMap);
```

Comment: компиляция прола, но к сожалению выдает ошибку при нажатии на кнопку `QObject::connect: signal not found in ob_panel`

Comment: @Insider, тут уже стоит воспользоваться советом @Xplatforms и оформить секцию сигнала как `signals`, а не `public` (в ob_panel.h).

Comment: при оформлении в секцию сикнала 
`void ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, Q_NULLPTR);
}`

получаю следующую ошибку `../moc_ob_panel.cpp:133: error: multiple definition of ``ob_panel::on_pB_Switch_clicked()'`

Comment: @Insider ох) Нужно убрать (вообще!) реализацию сигнала из cpp. Qt MOC пытается ее сгенерировать и натыкается на вашу.

Comment: понял) мои чуть ли не самые первые опыты с этим). А если я буду добавлять какие-то ивенты в кнопку дополнительно, что делать?

Comment: @Insider, Если вам нужно выделять какие-то другие события, то нужно будет добавить другие сигналы.

Comment: еще один маленький вопрос, если со свойством `checkable`, как мне отловить этот статус в функции `switchVideoMap`

Comment: @Insider, ваш слот должен иметь такие же аргументы, как в сигнале. Я настоятельно советую вам почитать/посмотреть [примеры в документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), сразу отпадет большинство вопросов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67699/discussion-between-insider-and-free-ze).